# Editing fiction and proofreading

Tags: creative-writing

I wrote the sentence:Our next door neighbors that lived on either side of the fence were shooting them off, although we could barely see them because of the huge Lilac bushes that separated our yard from their's.

Spelling and check has an issue with the word "their's" at the end of the sentence.  Is there anything wrong with using their's?

Comment: Remove "next door" since they live on either side of the fence, this is clear. I would delete "from theirs" entirely as extraneous and change yard to yards. My $.02.

Answer (score 2):

"Their's" isn't a word. The correct term is "theirs."

In most cases, you would add an apostrophe and an "s" to show possession. (For example: "It was the dog's bone.") However, an apostrophe is unnecessary when using these words:

> **he > his** (It was his money. The money was his.)
>
> **she > her/hers** (It was her money. They money was hers.)
>
> **it > its** (It was its money. The money was its.)
>
> **them > their/theirs** (It was their money. The money was theirs.)
>
> **you > your/yours** (It was your money. The money was yours.)

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's supposed to be "theirs" instead.  Spellcheck doesn't always work right, but sometimes it does.  Try a grammar book if you're still confused, consult a grammar book.

Answer (score 0):

People sometimes get confused with "hers" "its" "theirs".

Just remember, they're in the same family as "his"—and you wouldn't write hi's.